# setRTLTextPlugin cannot be called multiple times - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I'm using `mapboxgl` library in reactjs.
my map inside a tab. when I switch between tabs I got this error.

```
    componentDidMount() {


        mapboxgl.accessToken = '*****';
        mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin(
            'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.2.3/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js',
            null,
            true // Lazy load the plugin
        );
}
```

but I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: setRTLTextPlugin cannot be called multiple times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
if (mapboxgl.getRTLTextPluginStatus() !== 'loaded') {mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin('...') }
```

Comment: Use `mapboxgl.getRTLTextPluginStatus() === 'unavailable'` if the plugin is loaded lazily

Answer (score 4):

there is a solution here you can [check](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8585) to simplify your search this is what you have to do

```js
if (mapboxgl.getRTLTextPluginStatus() === 'unavailable') {
  mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin(
    'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.2.3/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js',
    (): void => {},
    true // Lazy load the plugin only when text is in arabic
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem can be solved with this code :

```js
  if (!window.mapboxRTLTextPluginSet) {
    mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin('../../assets/mapbox/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js');
    window.mapboxRTLTextPluginSet = true;
  }
```