# setRTLTextPlugin cannot be called multiple times in functional reactjs || nextjs

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, next.js, react-hooks, mapbox

I use **mapbox**. In production mode, I have no problem and the map is displayed correctly, but when I run npm run dev and it is in development mode, I get the following error. I know the reason is because strict mode is active and useEffect is executed twice. I don't know how to unmount so that this code doesn't run twice.
Tell me the solution without disabling strict mode.

**error:setRTLTextPlugin cannot be called multiple times**

```
useEffect(() => {
if (mapboxgl.getRTLTextPluginStatus() !== 'loaded') {
  mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin('api address');
}
```

}, []);

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308210/setrtltextplugin-cannot-be-called-multiple-times-reactjs.